# Rules mismatch between Outlook and Exchange

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, rules

Each time I open the Rule Wizard (Rules and Alerts) in Outlook 365 I get the following alert:

[image]

What I tried:

- I first tried clicking "Server" as advised, but the alert appears again when opening Rule Wizard.
- I also tried pressing the "Client" button to no avail.
- I checked Office 365 updates, but my installation is already updated to the last version.

Here is my Outlook version:

[image]

Is there something I can do to sync Outlook and Exchange rulesets once and for all?

Comment: You'll want to login to webmail (https://outlook.office365.com) and check the rules there. See why they are different. If you want to sync them, delete all on webmail and recreate locally. Alternatively, construct them on webmail only (limited)

Comment: You may need to reduce the Server rules (to less than 50), check this thread and see if it helps.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1b5d268f-014b-4914-ad6a-d10165262d24/rules-do-not-match?forum=exchangesvrclients

Comment: @LPChip, Aidan: thank you for your comments: logging to the webmail and cleaning up the rules solved the problem

Comment: This is so broken.

Answer (score -1):

Use outlook.exe /cleanclientrules to keep the server rules only and clear the Rules Wizard warning.

Full details can be found here
https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/client-server-side-rules/